# Send email to Outlook Group Mailbox through Workflow

Tags: list, workflow, outlook, sharepoint-email

I have a workflow that runs when a new list item is created in my SharePoint. I have the completed item being sent to individuals but now I need it to send to a group mailbox.

How do I go about this in my workflow?

Answer (score 1):

The way I got around this was setting up my workflow to e-mail myself, creating a rule in Outlook that recognized a unique subject (like "[SP] New Item Created"), and redirected it to desired group. More information on Outlook rules here: https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-c24f5dea-9465-4df4-ad17-a50704d66c59

I think the only other alternative is to manually recreate your mailbox group as a Sharepoint group.

Site Settings > People and groups > Groups > New > New Group (e.g. Custom Sharepoint Group)

That way it will be searchable via the workflow.
[image: Workflow Example]